# grails button to do ajax call to change textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails, gsp

I have a method in my controller

```
def returnJames = {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject()
    jsonObject.put("name","James")
    return jsonObject
}
```

and then I have a view:

```
<html>
<!--import gsp that has all the jquery imports-->
<script>
function changeName()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"<g:createLink url="[action:'returnJames',controller:'mycontroller']" />",
            dataType: "json",
            asnyc: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $('mytextbox').val(it.name)
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<g:form controller="mycontroller" method="post" >
<g:textField name="mytextbox" value="" />
<button name = "mybutton" id = "mybutton" onclick="changeName()">change name</button>
</g:form>
</html>
```

However it just tries to change the page to the index view of the mycontroller controller which doesn't exist.  How can I get it to just fill in the textbox with "James"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User `render` instead of `return`

```
render jsonObject
```

and change in jQuery

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#mytextbox').val(data.name)
}
```

change button to

```
<input type="button" id = "mybutton" onclick="changeName()" value="change name"/>
```